# SharePoint 2019 search issue

Tags: sharepoint-server

I have configured search service application in SharePoint 2019. All the installation and configuration went well. Then I went to content sources and ran the full crawl on the local SharePoint sites. The crawl is happening only to web application and not the content or sites inside the web application. If I create a new content source and give the full path of the site collection it crawl only the site collection and not the documents or list inside the site collection.not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

When creating content source, in the **Crawl Settings** section, make sure you select "Crawl everything under the hostname for each start address":
[image]

After the above, do a Full crawl again.